# Postgres JSONB Data Type Mapping using C# and Dapper

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper

I have a system that audits DB row add/edit/delete operations via a Postgres function with signature:

```sql
 func_audit_record(p_table_name  TEXT,
                   p_action_name TEXT,
                   p_old_row     JSONB,
                   p_new_row     JSONB,
                   p_edited_by   INTEGER)
```

This function has been executed directly via other Postgres functions up until this point, but now I need to execute it via C# directly.

How do I go about mapping a C# data type to the Postgres `JSONB` data-type while maintaining the above signature?

```cs
public async Task AuditAddAsync(string tableName, string actionName, JsonDocument oldRow, JsonDocument newRow, int appUserId)
    {
      var obj = new
      {
        p_audit_table_name = tableName,
        p_audit_action_name = actionName,
        p_old_row_state_as_text = oldRow, //JsonDocument object is too complex here
        p_new_row_state_as_text = newRow, //JsonDocument object is too complex here
        p_edited_by_user_id = appUserId,
        p_system_action = isSystemAction,
        p_notes = auditNotes
      };
      await _dapperAdapter.ExecuteAsync("func_audit_record", obj);
    }
```

I've tried with `JsonDocument` above (which seems to have the correct structure in the `RootElement` property), but that's too complex. Also, running JsonDocument.RootElement.ToString() throws an error since the function func_audit_record is expecting `JSONB`, not `TEXT`.

I really don't want to need to create a duplicate func_audit_record with TEXT parameters.

Ideas?

Comment: You should leverage Postgres extensions for doing data audit, instead of trying to manually do them via C# - it will be so inefficient. Look at [Temporal table](https://pgxn.org/dist/temporal_tables/) extension, by creating triggers you can also capture the user that made the data change or delete.

Comment: If you insist on making your code work and want to pass jsonb to your plpgsql function, then you can use Dapper's ICustomQueryParameter, as shown in this [example](https://dapper-tutorial.net/knowledge-base/56283658/how-do-i-pass-json-as-a-primitive-postgresql-type-to-a-function-using-dapper-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your code work. To pass `json` to your `plpgsql` function, use Dapper's `ICustomQueryParameter`, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57534990/5779732)